# Transferring Cypher Queries from CYPHERL Files to Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm currently dealing with data in the form of Cypher queries (CREATE and MERGE clauses) within a CYPHERL file, and I need to import this data into Memgraph. Can anyone guide me on how to import CYPHERL files into Memgraph effectively, either via Memgraph Lab or mgconsole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import data in the form of Cypher queries (e.g. `CREATE` and `MERGE` clauses) within a CYPHERL file into Memgraph, you can use either Memgraph Lab or `mgconsole`. The benefit of importing data using the CYPHERL file is that you need only one file to import both nodes and relationships. However, it can be challenging to write the queries for creating nodes and relationships yourself. If you haven't written any queries yet, you can refer to the Cypher manual.

To import data via Memgraph Lab, go to the Import & Export section after connecting to your Memgraph instance, and select the CYPHERL file to import or drag and drop it into Memgraph Lab. You can import up to 1 million nodes and relationships using the CYPHERL file.

To import data via mgconsole, run mgconsole in non-interactive mode and import data saved in a CYPHERL file after starting Memgraph. You can import queries saved in, for example, queries.cypherl, by issuing the following shell command:

```
mgconsole < queries.cypherl
```

If you installed and started Memgraph using Docker, you will need to run the client using the following command:

```
docker run -i --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform --host HOST < queries.cypherl
```

Remember to replace HOST with a valid IP of the container and define the correct Memgraph Docker image you are using, as well as the correct path to the file.